# Null and alternative hypothesis

Tags: r, statistics

The sentiment of a tweet (positive, neural or negative) is not independent of the appearance of the word "apple" in the tweet.

What is the null hypothesis and the alternative hypothesis?

Comment: Is this related to programming? Also i tried to read some questions for `r` tag , am still confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely not related to programming.

The null hypothesis (denoted by H0) states that there will not be any observed effect for your experiment. So it can be stated as:

> The sentiment of a tweet (positive, neural or negative) is independent of the appearance of the word "apple" in the tweet.

Or:

> The appearance of the word "apple" does not predict sentiment in a tweet.

The alternative hypothesis (H1 or Ha) states the opposite, that you will observe an effect as a result of the experiment, and it can be expressed simply as the negation of H0:

> There is a relationship between the sentiment of a tweet (positive, neural or negative) and the appearance of the word "apple" in the tweet.

Or it can be a statement as to the expected result, for example:

> A tweet that contains the word "apple" is more likely to be positive.